# Accessing '-Denvironment' properties within Spring app

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, environment-variables

I need to access database configuration settings that are stored in Denvironment properties files. I can't figure out how to access these variables within my Spring app.
I tried accessing them with:

```
@Value("${datasource.url}")
private String databaseUrl;
```

But this seems to not find anything, as `databaseUrl` is null.

I could alternatively load the properties filed myself, but I still need to know which environment is selected (dev or prod), and I can't seem to access that with `@Value`.

Comment: Is this located inside a Spring bean? Because if it is, it should cause an exception to be thrown, indicating that the property can't be found (the property name is `spring.datasource.url`). If it's not in a Spring bean, then Spring won't care about the annotation.

Comment: @JBNizet No, this is located in a utility class that is called by a controller. Would I need to move this code to the spring controller for the properties to be accessible?

Comment: Spring doesn't inject anything in random classes. Only in Spring beans. So this field must be part of a Spring bean. Choose what's the best bean is for this field.

Comment: That makes sense, and the denvironment variables can be accessed now. Thank you!